# ImproperlyConfigured url

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I was trying Django REST Framework. I am using Django 1.10 and DRF 3.6.2.

**What have I missed, can anybody please tell me!!!**

I have created an "api" app in a sample django project. In my serializers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['url', 'username', 'email',]
```

In my views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import UserSerializer


class UserListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):

    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

In my projects urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('api.urls', namespace='users')),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),

]
```

In my app "api" urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/users', views.UserListAPIView.as_view(), name='user-list'),
]
```

It looks everything fine. But when I call the http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/

It is showing ---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove 'url' from fields it try to add detail view to the user, but you havent:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email',]
        #        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or try to use [readonlymodelviewset](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#readonlymodelviewset)

Comment: yes it works.. thanks.. the 'url' causes the problem. :)

Comment: Sir, you are like god to me. I have been trying to debug my project for 3 days but nothing helped till I came across this question.